# Solving inequality with multiple inequality signs.

Tags: inequality

I'm having trouble understanding what method to use when solving the following type of inequality:

Find all values for x

$$\frac{4x-33}{4x+33} < \frac{x+1}{x-1} \le \frac{25+4x}{25-4x} $$

I understand that you could make one side $0$ and then proceed from there if there were only 2 terms. I'm not sure when it's 3 though.

(I apologize for my english.)

Comment: Solve the first, second and third inequality and combine the answers?

Comment: Do you mean first solving "1st < 2nd" then the "2nd <= 3rd"?

Comment: Try to solve 1st < 2nd, 1st < 3rd, 2nd < 3rd and combine.

Comment: Okay I will try that, thanks!

Edit: Would the <= sign become a < sign? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: @Sai follow the guideline you gave yourself in your own commentary.

Comment: @mookid Ok thanks!

Comment: One possibility for each of the inequalities is to multiply through by the square of the denominator (which is always non-negative) - that increases the degree of the polynomials involved, but there will clearly be some significant cancellation. Care required when denominators are zero, though.